# To make HDF format files into tiff files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modis, geotiff-tiff, hdf

I have downloaded the MODIS Monthly Fire Location Product from the University of Maryland ftp Server. All the files are in HDF format.

How do you make these into tiff's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the HDF-EOS To GeoTIFF Conversion Tool (HEG) and the MODIS Reprojection Tool (MRT) can do that. You can download them from the USGS website: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/data_manipulation

Comment: Is the HDF-EOS To GeoTIFF Conversion Tool (HEG) part of ArcGIS?

Comment: @I.Stirs no it's not.

Comment: the link does not available any more

Comment: The MODIS Reprojection Tool (MRT) has been retired in favour of HEG. See https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/news/downloadable-modis-reprojection-tool-mrt-and-mrtswath-tool-have-been-retired/